# Org mode inline images with link abbreviations?

Tags: org-mode

I have a link abbreviation defined that just makes a file path relative to my org directory:

```lisp
(setq org-link-abbrev-alist
    `(
         ("orgdir" . ,(format "file://%s%%s" (file-name-as-directory org-directory)))
         ...
```

Unfortunately, links to image files no longer display inline:

```
This works:
[[~/org/foo/image.png]]
This doesn't:
[[orgdir:foo/image.png]]
```

Any way to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried `file:foo/image.png`? Press `C-c C-l` (`org-insert-link`) and choose `file:`. Then select the file and press `RET`.

Answer (score 0):

Solved: I wrote the abbreviation to resolve to a standard `file://` URL format but org mode just wants `file:`. With `org-directory` equal to `"~/org/"`, `[[orgdir:foo/image.png]]` resolves to `[[file://~/org/foo/image.png]]` when it should be `[[file:~/org/foo/image.png]]`. Changing the corresponding line in my `init.el` fixes it:

```lisp
(setq org-link-abbrev-alist
    `(
         ("orgdir" . ,(format "file:%s%%s" (file-name-as-directory org-directory)))
         ...
```